# Code Style not applied

Tags: format, settings, phpstorm

I'm trying to change PHP `Code Style` settings from `Settings|Editor|Code Style|PHP`.

From the `Scheme` dropdown I select `Project` and then change something. I finally click `Apply`. I open a PHP file I want to format and press `Ctrl+Alt+L`, the `Reformat Code` dialog pops up and I click `Run`. Well, the code is actually formatted but it doesn't use the modified settings.

I'm probably missing something obvious... Please help me.

Thank you

**More Details**

I'm trying to change this:

```
array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'hello' => 'world',
    'a' => 123
);
```

Into this:

```
array(
    'key1'  => 'value1',
    'hello' => 'world',
    'a'     => 123
);
```

By checking `Settings|Editor|Code Style|PHP|Wrapping and Braces|Array initializer|Align when multiline`.

IDE version is 8.0.2

Comment: please can you be more specific - what options did you change, what is the actual formatting result? BTW, do you have .editorconfig file anywhere in your project? Try disabling 'Enable editorconfig support' option in Settings|Editor|Code Style - does it make any difference?

Comment: @lena There isn't any .editorconfig file. There isn't any "Enable .editorconfig Support" option in "Settings|Editor|Code Style". It's v8.0.2 if that helps. I was just trying to make multiline arrays aligned checking "Wrapping and Braces|Array Initializer|Align when multiline" in "Settings|Editor|Code Style|PHP". The result is that multiline arrays aren't aligned at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By checking `Settings|Editor|Code Style|PHP|Wrapping and Braces|Array initializer|Align when multiline`.

You are using wrong formatting setting.

Correct option is **`PHP | Other | Array Declaration Style --> Align key-value pairs`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you that was the problem.

Comment: Hi! i am facing the same problem. I already set as per your solution. After reformatting by ctrl + Alt + L associative array elements are not in new line

Comment: @karim_fci That's because this option affects arrays that already have have their keys on separate lines. For you you first need to configure formatter to use such setup (look at `Wrapping & Braces` tab for such options).